# Handling routing in Vue with Strip Connect's redirect link

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments, vue-router

Flow: backend sends o-auth link to Vue, user clicks on link which directs to stripe's form, after completion of the form it directs user to a URL I have specified.

I have a vue client app that I want to use stripe connect with. From my backend app, I am sending a [o-auth link][1] where it will let users fill out their Stripe information and upon completion, it will redirect me to a URL I specify in Stripe settings(http://localhost:8080/test and this is valid in test mode).

The problem I am facing is that even though the link is correct, vue won't redirect to `test` page and stay on the current page. `test` page  renders when I redirect it via `<router-view></router-view>` in the template. I do have my router configured properly so I don't why it doesn't go to the redirect link and render that page.

my router setup:

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'mainContent',
      component: MainContent
    },
   {
      path: '/test',
      name: 'test',
      component: test
    },
    {
      path: '/manage',
      name: 'manage',
      component: Manage,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
      }
    },
  ]
})


  [1]: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts
```

Comment: This question isn't very clear. I'm not understanding how Stripe is even relevant - basically vue-router isn't behaving the way you expect when the url is /test. Please edit the question to make it more focused or clear.

Comment: yeah, when the stripe redirects to `/test`, the url is correct but the page is still on the previous page. But when I specify to go to `/test` via router(<router-view>), it works

Comment: I think you need a MRE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As others have suggested, this is not really Stripe related. You need to isolate your issue with the Vue router and figure out what isn't set up right. Here is a super simple example of Vue routing you can compare to and fork with your Stripe code to compare: https://qx3orn736q.csb.app/goodbye?name=friend

Comment: I'm having the same problem, was a solution ever discovered? No middleware in vue-router, but after the stripe redirect ("/signup") it immediately re-redirects to the base url ("/")

Answer (score 0):

The URL is not a true URL that you can enter into browser and end up at that page. The Vue router uses simulated URLS and handles them as guides to its own redirection. But they are not web pages as a web server wants them to be hence there is no page to go to when you enter the URL. In contrast, Stripe does redirect to a standard web page and this requires that the web server finds that page and can serve it. Two completely different approaches to serving web content. This plays havoc with a Single Page Application particularly a reactive one like VueJs. Various guidance did not work for me.

Thus, Stripe is not the culprit here although it is causing a situation that is endemic to VueJS and Vue Router. It is described in the Vue Router documentation under HTML5 History mode [hash mode simulates URL while history mode achieves URL navigation](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) this issue requires making changes to VueRouter config, possibly to web server (e.g. httpd , nginx,..) and your page scripts.

> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their browser. Now that's ugly.

I solved this problem with trial & error to figure out how to allow Stripe to do redirect while still maintaining state in the VueJs pages. The result was that since Stripe calls with a GET including a query string I had it sent to the index.html file of my my VueJs app and then captured the query, checked it to see if it was from Stripe, and if so, added the query string to browser SessionState and then used Vue router to go to page I wanted. Once there, I got SessionState in mounted() and from that got back into VueJs page state and store state. This is a bit circuitous but only way I got working on client side without having to cross security controls on server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35727909)